# isset($_COOKIE['name'])) not working

Tags: php, cookies, isset

So I am making a blog for myself and to give myself admin privileges I set a cookie. **I have manually checked its existence.**

**And I have tested the code on my laptop using apache server and the code works fine.**

I have two php pages

First one detects the cookie fine, I post onto this php page from a form.

```
<?php



if(isset($_POST['tt'])){

    if(isset($_COOKIE['name'])){
        echo "something";
```

something is printed

The above page is the only page that detects the cookie I have 7 more files none of them detects the cookie. I will post the main page here

```
    if(isset($_GET['cat'])){
    $t = $_GET['cat'];
    $mod = "where `cat`=$t";
}

    $ref = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `content`".$mod);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ref)){
        $tit = $row['title'];
        $cno= $row['cno'];
        $brief = $row['brief'];
        $cat = $row['cat'];
        $time = $row['time'];
        $t = "";
        if(isset($_COOKIE['name'])) echo "something";
```

the something is not printed

also
1)Except the first code segment, none of the other pages uses a post method and retrieves data **prior** to checking the cookie.The rest of the pages sometimes have a get method before the checking the cookie like I have shown above, but none uses a post method before checking the cookie
2)var_dump['$_COOKIE'] yields only unrelated cookies set by my hosting provider.

I guess this is a php configuration problem may be ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cookie might be a path cookie, meaning that it will be sent only to one page. Use the Firebug "Cookies" tab (or similar tool) to check if this is the case, and use the Firebug "Network" tab (or similar tool, or Wireshark) to check if the cookie is actually sent by the browser.

Comment: That worked out like a charm !! Setting the path for the cookie worked out ! But I wonder why it didnt have any problems while I was testing it locally .. I used the same file structure.

Comment: My guess: the cookie was set differently earlier and stayed that way.

Comment: Nope, I just put the whole code in a archive and extracted it in my hosting. So the cookie setting code was same.

Answer (score 3):

Where/how are you setting the cookie? There is a[n] (optional) 4th `path` argument when setting PHP cookies:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

**For example:**

`setcookie("cookiename","cookievalue", $time);` will only set it for the current URL path

Whereas: `setcookie("cookiename","cookievalue", $time,"/");`  will set the cookie for all pages/folders on that domain,

If you press CTRL+SHIFT+J in google chrome, and click on the Resources tab, you can find the cookies and the path it is valid in. I'd check that out. perhaps this is why?